# Find old branch of debian jessie

Tags: debian, branch, mirror, debian-jessie

Following my precedent post I found that the problem came from the version of Debian I use is too recent.

So I am searching for a repository of an old branch with a mirror or something like that but I do not know where to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You will find jessie (and wheezy) packages in:  http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/

The previous version are still stored, but not in usual mirror, but into http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/

Comment: First thank you for your answer
I am searching specific packages that I can not retrieve with "apt-get", is there a way to find them ?